# Replace with a regex python

Tags: python, regex

I want to delete all the words that start with TIPE_ and "END_TIPE" from a sentence, how could this be done with a regex in python?

Example sentence:

```
x = "Hello, my name is TIPE_PER María END_TIPE and I'm from TIPE_LOC Europa END_TIPE"
```

This should be like this:
Hello, my name is María and I'm from Europa

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?
What doesn't work with your code and where is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution assumes that *TIPE_...* are always followed by a space, and that *END_TIPE* always has a space in front of it. It seems like you want to delete those spaces also.

It finds all those occurrences and replaces it with an empty string `""`.

```py
import re
x = "Hello, my name is TIPE_PER María END_TIPE and I'm from TIPE_LOC Europa END_TIPE"
re.sub("(TIPE_.*? | END_TIPE)", "", x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex `(\S+_)*TIPE\S* *` that will look for TIPE and any non-whitespace after and any non-whitespace and _ before and will remove them from the text, in addition, it will remove one space after the matching word from the better formating.

```
import re

x = "Hello, my name is TIPE_PER María END_TIPE and I'm from TIPE_LOC Europa END_TIPE"
print(re.sub(r"(\S+_)*TIPE\S* *", "", x))
```

Output

```
Hello, my name is María and I'm from Europa
```

Comment: Why do you use  `(\S+_)*`? What it is for?

Comment: To check for any non-whitespace characters and an underscore together before of  TIPE

Comment: So you are matching `abc*$!_123()ç@_TIPE$%§;?                  ` and replace this with nothing, that is not what is wanted.

Answer (score -1):

hello so follow the code from below everything is commented and explained perfectly.

```py
import re#imports regular expressions libary/module
text="Hello, my name is TIPE_PER María END_TIPE and I'm from TIPE_LOC Europa END_TIPE"#the string of text
pattern=r"(TIPE_PER|END_TIPE|TIPE_LOC)"#pattern TIPE_PER OR END_TIPE OR TIPE_LOC
resault=re.sub(pattern,"",text)#.sub maens replace so you are basickly replacing every math with that pattern in that text string with nothing or ""
print(resault)#prints the resault
```

Comment: (You might need to fix up your formatting)

Comment: can you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: There's a help in the post editor that explains it.

Comment: yeah i just read it thank you guys <3

Answer (score -1):

This one should work as you wanted.

```
import re
s = "Hello, my name is TIPE_PER María END_TIPE and I'm from TIPE_LOC Europa END_TIPE"
replaced = re.sub('TIPE_\w+|END_TIPE', '', s)

print(replaced)
```